# How to store Hex and convert Hex to ASCII in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, data-conversion

My Command output is something like `0x53 0x48 0x41 0x53 0x48 0x49`. Now i need to store this in a hex value and then convert it to ASCII as `SHASHI`.

What i tried-

1. I tried to store the values in hex as `int("0x31",16)` then decode this to ASCII using `decode("ascii")` but no luck.
2. `"0x31".decode("utf16")`this throws an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Some other stuffs with random encoding and decoding whatever found through `Google`. But still no luck.

Question :- How can i store a value in Hex like `0x53 0x48 0x41 0x53 0x48 0x49` and convert it's value as `SHASHI` for verification.

Note: Not so friendly with Python, so please excuse if this is a novice question.

Comment: Why do you want to store a hex string instead of just storing a list of ints? Or just a `bytes` or `bytearray`, which already acts like a list of ints. Then you don't need any of this code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `int("0x31", 16)` part is correct:

```
>>> int("0x31",16)
49
```

But to convert that to a character, you should use the [`chr(...)` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) instead:

```
>>> chr(49)
'1'
```

Putting both of them together (on the first letter):

```
>>> chr(int("0x53", 16))
'S'
```

And processing the whole list:

```
>>> [chr(int(i, 16)) for i in "0x53 0x48 0x41 0x53 0x48 0x49".split()]
['S', 'H', 'A', 'S', 'H', 'I']
```

And finally turning it into a string:

```
>>> hex_string = "0x53 0x48 0x41 0x53 0x48 0x49"
>>> ''.join(chr(int(i, 16)) for i in hex_string.split())
'SHASHI'
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = b'SHASHI'
>>> myWord = binascii.b2a_hex(s)
>>> myWord
b'534841534849'
>>> binascii.a2b_hex(myWord)
b'SHASHI'


>>> bytearray.fromhex("534841534849").decode()
'SHASHI'
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this input:

`s = '0x53 0x48 0x41 0x53 0x48 0x49'`

You can **store** values in list like follow:

`l = list(map(lambda x: int(x, 16), s.split()))`

To **convert** it to ASCII use [chr()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#chr):

`res = ''.join(map(chr, l))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is OK for your problem but it's a nice way to convert HEX to ASCII. The code snippet is below:

```py
# Your raw data, the hex input
raw_data = '0x4D6172697573206120636974697420637520707974686F6E21'

# Slice string to remove leading `0x`   
hex_string = raw_data[2:]

# Convert to bytes object.                                          
bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(hex_string) 

# Convert to ASCII representation.                          
ascii_string = bytes_object.decode("ASCII") 

# print the values for comparison
print("\nThe input data is: {} \nwhile the string is: {} \n".format(raw_data,ascii_string))
```