# how can i read a files hex content and write that to a hex file

Tags: python, python-3.x

so heres my current code

```
import binascii
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
f.close()


with open('wmhex.txt','w')as g:
    g.write(content)
g.close()
```

the problem is that I can only write the hex data of the old file into the hex data of the new file, essentially duplicating the file. I want to write it as text to the file, but I cant figure out how to handle the hex as a string.

Comment: Try "binascii.hexlify" function.

Comment: Michael Buttscher the problem is that i would be hexing the decoded text, which uses a different encoding. also, 'TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'

Comment: michael butscher im not able to use binasci.hexlify because i cant write to a text file wit it, i can only write that to a file's hexadecimal content, which would be creating a duplicate file. i want to have the hex data from this fie in a txt document

Comment: can you do `str(binascii.hexlify)`? Just trying to contribute.

Comment: @Tre Rossi Where are you converting the input hex content into plaintext?  If you're never modifying the input before writing it to the output, shouldn't it still be the same?

Comment: Try this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49400877/7548672

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from binascii import hexlify

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
f.close()


with open('wmhex.txt','wb')as g:
    g.write(hexlify (content))
g.close()
```