# How to Convert hex+character to Character in Python

Tags: javascript, python, css, encoding, utf-8

```
Str = """\\x3Cstyle\\x3E\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20.mainDiv\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x7B\\x0A\\x20\\x20width\\x3A1000px\\x3B\\x0A\\x20\\x20background\\x2Dimage\\x3Aurl"""
```

I need the output as:

```
<style\> 
.mainDiv
{
width\:1000px;
background-image:URL

}
```

I need to Decode it using Python

Comment: when I do `print(Str)` then I get expected `<style> .mainDiv { width:1000px; background-image:URL` - simply there is nothing to convert - you write it in code as `\x3C` but Python keeps it as `<`

Comment: do you have this `Str` in Python code or in JavaScript code? In Python it shouldn't need any conversion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store Hex and convert Hex to ASCII in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400780/how-to-store-hex-and-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question, [How to store Hex and convert Hex to ASCII in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400780/how-to-store-hex-and-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-python/49400877)

Comment: I scrapped that code from A website and stored it in a variable as text..now I want it to be in A properly Parsed Manner.....and I tried print(str) but it shows the same output

Comment: porblem is that you didn't format code in question and it was showing different string - without double \\. Now code is correctly formatted and I see problem.

Comment: How did you scrape it ? Probably you used wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `'raw_unicode_escape'` with `'unicode_escape'`

```
Str = """\\x3Cstyle\\x3E\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20.mainDiv\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x7B\\x0A\\x20\\x20width\\x3A1000px\\x3B\\x0A\\x20\\x20background\\x2Dimage\\x3Aurl"""

Str = Str.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')

print(Str)
```

---

Python doc: codecs [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)